# Distribution of ratio of two independent normal variables

Tags: regression, distributions, normal-distribution, joint-distribution

My objective is to find out the distribution of $A/B$ given $A \sim N(a,b); B \sim N(c,d)$.

I set $Z_1$ equal to $\frac{(A-a)}{\sqrt{b}}$ and $Z_2$ equals $\frac{(B-c)}{\sqrt{d}}$ such that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are both $N(0,1)$.

Then I let $U=\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}$ and try to find out $g(U)$ (standard Cauchy distribution).

Could someone please let me know whether I am on the right track or not?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I would want to know how to find out the joint distribution of A and B?

Comment: The distribution of $A/B$ is different than the joint distribution of $A$ and $B$. Which do you want to find?

Comment: @MattBrems I am interested to know the distribution(or behavior) of A/B.

Comment: Are A and B independent?

Comment: @MattBrems Yes they are

Comment: Then, yes, you're on the right track. Define C = A/B. Then C is Cauchy. If a=c=0 and b=d=1 (as you defined them above), then C ~ Cauchy(0,1). If a and c aren't 0 or b and d aren't 1, then the parameters will be different. If you standardize them as you did above, then U ~ Cauchy(0,1).

Comment: The difficulty is that $A/B$ is not a transform of $Z_1/Z_2$!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/86178/6633 where Moderator Glen_b's answer includes a link to a .pdf file which contains the full answer for the distribution of $A/B$ where $A$ and $B$ are jointly normal random variables with arbitrary means and variances. The answer is _not_ always Cauchy (only) as Matt Brems's comment seems to imply but is related to the Cauchy density.

Comment: @DilipSarwate  That is an excellent spot. That was a side-issue in that (rather confused) question though. For example, if at a later date somebody wanted to include a full derivation then it would arguably belong more at this question than at that one. And somebody searching for an answer to the "normal over normal" question would find the other issues on that thread a distraction. Arguably that thread might better be closed as a duplicate of this one, because of the "untidiness" there (that arose from asking a question from a partially false premise).

Comment: I can't quite face following it up at this time of night, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Transformation_properties) looks like it might be helpful here.

Comment: I don't believe this site contains a fully worked answer to this general question, but it does answer special cases and provides extensive references to answers, including http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33050, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3640, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175445, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47009, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162483, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28233. Since $Z_1/Z_2$ has a distinctly different distribution than $A/B$, using the $Z_i$ is of little help.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175445/distribution-of-ratio-of-correlated-normals