# Simulating ratio of two independent normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

I have two non centered independent normally distributed variables $X$ and $Y$.  Specifically
$$ X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$$ 
$$ Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$$

I am interested in sampling from the ratio $X/Y$. I know that the ratio is Cauchy distributed if the denominator distribution is centered at 0 which mine is not. My question is is there an approximate distribution that I can sample the ratio $X/Y$ from using the means and standard deviations from the normal distributions?

Comment: Please see the comments at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182915/distribution-of-ratio-of-two-independent-normal-variables for some background information.

Comment: If you just want to simulate the ratio, why not simply do that? i.e. simulate X and Y and compute X/Y? Trying to compute the distribution and simulate that seems like a lot of work by comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only interested in sampling from this ratio distribution, you can do that directly without knowing the distribution function of the ratio (exactly or approximately). Here is how I would do it in R:

```
rmyratio <- function(n, mean, sd) {
    rnorm(n, mean[1], sd[1]) / rnorm(n, mean[2], sd[2])
    }
X  <-  rmyratio(1000, 0:1, c(1,5))
hist(X)
```

If you for some other purpose want to know the exact distribution, it can be found in [https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Distributions-Involving-Gaussian-Variables/dp/0387346570/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1531341533&sr=1-1&keywords=gaussian+distribution+engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387346570)  (I am sure, but didn't look)

Answer (score 2):

An exact expression for the ratio of two correlated normal random variables was given by [Hinkley in 1969](http://static.stevereads.com/papers_to_read/on_the_ratio_of_two_correlated_normal_random_variables.pdf). The notation is taken from the [stackexchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398436/a-b-testing-ratio-of-sums)

For $Z = \frac{X}{Y}$ with $$
\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix} \mu_x \\ \mu_y \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_x^2 & \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y \\ \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y  & \sigma_y^2   \end{bmatrix} \right)
$$

The exact probability density function (pdf) result is:

$$f(z) = \frac{b(z)d(z)}{a(z)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_X\sigma_Y} \left[  \Phi \left( \frac{b(z)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}a(z)} \right) - \Phi \left( - \frac{b(z)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}a(z)} \right) \right] + \frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Y a(z)^2} \exp \left( -\frac{c}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)
$$ with $$ \begin{array}{}
a(z) &=& \left( \frac{z^2}{\sigma_X^2} - \frac{2 \rho z}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} + \frac{1}{\sigma_Y^2} \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}} \\ 
b(z) &=& \frac{\mu_X z}{ \sigma_X^2} - \frac{\rho (\mu_X+ \mu_Y z)}{ \sigma_X \sigma_Y} + \frac{\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y^2} \\
c &=& \frac{\mu_X^2}{\sigma_Y^2} - \frac{2 \rho \mu_X \mu_Y + }{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} + \frac{\mu_Y^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\\
d(z) &=& \text{exp} \left(  \frac {b(z)^2 - c a(z) ^2}{2(1-\rho^2)a(z)^2}\right) 
 \end{array}$$

And an approximation of the CDF based on an asymptotic behaviour is: (for $\theta_Y/\sigma_Y \to \infty$): $$
 F(z) \to \Phi\left( \frac{z - \mu_X/\mu_Y}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y a(z)/\mu_Y} \right)
 $$

You end up with the Delta method result when you insert the approximation $a(z) = a(\mu_X/\mu_Y)$ $$a(z) \sigma_X \sigma_Y /\mu_Y \approx a(\mu_X/\mu_Y)  \sigma_X \sigma_Y /\mu_Y = \left( \frac{\mu_X^2\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^4} - \frac{2 \mu_X \sigma_X \sigma_Y}{\mu_Y^3} + \frac{\sigma_X^2}{\mu_Y^2} \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of information about the ratio you are looking for [at this nice Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Gaussian_ratio_distribution).

[image: pdf of function]

However, if you just want to sample, you can do that as well, easily using R code...

```
# set up variables
num.samples <- 100000
mu1 <- 1
mu2 <- 2
sd1 <- 4
sd2 <- 9

# simulate norms
norms1 <- rnorm(n=num.samples, mean=mu1, sd=sd1)
norms2 <- rnorm(n=num.samples, mean=mu2, sd=sd2)

# do ratio
ratio.dist <- norms1 / norms2

# to sample, use sample() 
sample(ratio.dist, size=1)

# You can see the density plot as well...
plot(density(ratio.dist))
```

Comment: I added my contribution after @kjetil, so you should accept their answer if it is what you are looking for.